# ASP.NET Core. Bower dependencies are not copied to wwwroot

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bower

I have an ASP.Core project (Visual studio 2015) and I installed bootstrap to it by 'Manage Bower packages'

[image]

I see package in the project dependencies

[image]

But wwwroot is empty and I cannot access js and css files from my views.

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe because your bower.json do not specify the output directory? Dunno where you created the template from or if its an old/manual addtion, but the newer ASP.NET core templates in Visual Studio should have a bower.json file which sets "wwwroot" as output directory and directly restore the packages there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower scroll down to the "Manual installation in bower.json" section

Answer (score 7):

You should use either: a bower settings file or a processor like gulp or webpack:

### Option1: Bower Config

docs: https://bower.io/docs/config/

in short. you can create a `.bowerrc` file with `{ directory": "wwwroot/bower_components" }`.

Now if you `bower install` your dependencies it will add them to wwwroot/bower_components instead.

For big, SEO related projects option2 is prefered though:

### Option2: Processing

you can use tools like gulp to minify files before adding them to the wwwroot.

It add an extra step/complexity. but the advantage is smaller files (minification) + you only copy what you need resulting in a smaller published package.

in `gulpfile.js` you can do something like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bower = require("./bower.json");
gulp.task("copy", function() {
  var resources = bower.webResources;
  var tasks = resources.map(function(resource) {
    return gulp.src("./bower_components/" + resource)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/')); //copy globpath to wwwroot/lib
  });
  return merge(tasks);
});
```

and then you can add a webResources list to your bower.json to define what needs to be copied:

```
"webResources": [ //bootstrap example, with globbing
  "bootstrap/dist/**/@(bootstrap.css|glyphicons-halflings-regular.*|bootstrap.js)",
]
```

## Recommended Use Webpack2

You can use webpack2 to merge all web dependencies: Javascript, css, fonts, images into a single javascript file.

Downsides: 
* It will increase the build time, since webpack will now have to compile as well. (Pro: You can use devserver to build on demand).
* Delta updates will be less efficient

Pro:
* You get a single file as dependency
* You can use latest javascript/typescript features and transpile&shim so it works on every browser.

Answer (score 3):

As it ofter happens, the problem was found soon after post this question. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

**Quick answer**: Add *bower.json* to your project manually and then add dependencies.

**Long answer**:
After you click to 'Show all files' there were no file 'bower.js'. I added it in 'add new item' for a project

[image]

[image]

and added this code

```
{
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
       "jquery": "3.1.1"
    }
}
```

After it reloaded and copied packages to wwwroot

Comment: The idea is to use a processor like gulp or webpack to compile/minify/concat your javascripts and then put hte compiled code inside the wwwroot.

Comment: I have added jQuery 3.2.1 to an ASP.NET 2.0 Web project and I have a bower.json file and a .bowerrc file. When using the "Manager Bower packages" GUI, the jQuery files where added as expected under wwwroot/lib/jQuery/dist. The project is under GIT source control and by default files like jquery.js is excluded. When you clone the GIT repo to another computer, how is the jquery.js file supposed to be re-created? A VS 2017 Build does not do it.

Answer (score 3):

## Adding Bower Packages to ASP.Net 2.1

### Add Bower Packages

- In Toolbar `Project => Quick Install Packages`    (shortcut => shift Alt 0)
- Choose Bower
- Type in Package Name e.g Bootstrap
- Choose the Version and click Install
- Create in root of solution two files
- Bower.json
- .bowerrc

### Create a Bower.json file

```json
{
  "name": "RazorPagesMovie",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Add the package names and versions

### Create a .bowerrc file

This is the file that is critical as its here we name the path our files are to be made available ( our static files )

```json
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Add the directory to .bowerrc where you wish the files to be made available for development / production.

- You may need to restore packages with dotnet restore in the cli or right click on bower.json and click bower restore packages.
- Look in wwwroot. You should see a lib folder with your packages inside.
- Add the files paths to your script tags within your _Layout.cshtml file

```json
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy">
</script>
```

- NB check if you also need to update any css link files or change version references.